# How to set a value in package.json from a local configuration file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend

For example:

```
"name": "component 1",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "author": {
    "name": "Pedro",
    "email": "pedro@naoinformado.com .br"
  },
```

I have multiple angular projects within a single project and whenever I need to change the version, name and email values ​​I need to change manually.

How to leave this without code redundancy and have these values ​​in a single place where package.json could read from there

I tried to create a file called configuration.js and have these settings there but to no avail

Comment: Where is package.json file located? In the server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this in a json file itself, because the json file format is meant to be a static file (no dynamic values). You *can't* do something like this: `"key": {externalfile.<value>}`.

You can, however, create a script to run yourself whenever you want to change a lot of values. Take a look at the `npm-pkg` command. [Link here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-pkg). You can create a bash script to update key value pairs in multiple angular projects and store the values to be updated in a config file of your choosing. This config file could even be another json file if you prefer. Or you could store those values in the bash script itself.

If you don't want to create a bash script file, you may want a parent package.json file and put a script there that changes values in other package.json files. Don't put the script to change values in a package.json file you want to change, as it may cause weird errors. Also, I don't recommend creating a package.json script to do this, as package.file script is supposed to contain package information, and creating a file called `update_package_json_files.sh` would be more visible and make more logical sense.

Comment: Actually, while researching this question, I discovered `$ref`. You may want to look at that, as it seems to be able to accomplish the effect you desire.